# FullCalendar - best way to add fully custom prev/next buttons?

Tags: reactjs, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

My goal is to build out completely custom buttons for the prev/next functionality, not just using icon strings like the ones from font-awesome for instance, but with a custom in-house "element", which is basically a component by itself. I'm aware of the `customButtons` object specified in the [docs](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/customButtons), but that doesn't achieve the objective here to add fully custom buttons, since that one is still a "FullCalendar" flavored button with its own background and stuff, plus the `customButtons` approach requires passing strings, whereas my custom button will be an element. What I'm trying to achieve is something like the following (I'm using version 5 in case it helps):

```
const myCustomPrevBtn = {
  return <CustomButton onClick={()=>{}}>Prev</CustomButton >
}
const myCustomNextBtn = {
  return <CustomButton onClick={()=>{}}>Next</CustomButton >
}

 <FullCalendar 
     headerToolbar={{
       left:'myCustomPrevBtn',
       right:'myCustomNextBtn'
     }} 
     plugins={[dayGridPlugin, timeGridPlugin]} 
     initialView="timeGridWeek" 
  />
```

I was thinking about *not* using FullCalendar's default `headerToolbar` at all (since we're talking custom components for the prev/next buttons) by doing `headerToolbar={{false}}`, but not sure how I'd let the user move between the previous or next week/day/month if I take that route. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: So you want this just for visual difference of the buttons? Or do they need to do some extra functionality as well? It's possible to theme the calendar, so you could style the buttons that way - and then it would be consistent across all buttons, not just prev/next.

Comment: If you want to make buttons completely independent of the calendar though, you can - fullcalendar has next() and prev() methods in its API you can call to do the same task, so you could just make your buttons call those methods.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look into it @ADyson, I went with the second approach. Used ref to expose the `next` and `prev` functions and just used those in my custom buttons, which are supposed to be completely independent of the calendar.

Comment: @ADyson apologies if it breaks SO's policies, I had another question pertaining to FullCalendar's API, I was looking up the topic before posting my question and saw that you answered one of the questions. Any chance you had some insight into this? - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73480491/fullcalendar-v5-best-way-to-update-full-list-of-events-in-react

Answer (score 3):

For anyone seeing this in the future, I ended up accessing the calendar API by using ref. So for instance, I was passing a ref to my `FullCalendar` component, then inside the event handler for my custom buttons that I needed to use, I accessed the calendar API's `prev`/`next` functions using that ref's current value -

```
<FullCalendar
  ref={testRef}
  headerToolbar={false}
  plugins={[dayGridPlugin, timeGridPlugin]}
  initialView="timeGridWeek"
  initialEvents={[//some events list]}
/>

// then inside my custom handler
  const handlePreviousClick = () => {
    const calendarAPI = calendarRef?.current?.getApi();
    calendarAPI?.prev();
  };
```

Hope it helps.